# htaccess set specific file to download only

Tags: file, .htaccess, download

I'm working on developing a javascript framework and I don't want anyone to be able to link to the "nightly build" .js file directly on the server.

Based on my research from google, here's what I have in my htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch /development/flanvas/flanvas.js>
 ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

And I've also tried putting a .htaccess file in /development/flanvas/ and adding:

```
AddType applicaton/octet-stream.js
```

Neither have worked so far :(

*edit

I suppose if a user really wanted to snag this, they could curl/ajax it. Is it advised to have the .htaccess check the HTTP_REFERER instead? This could potentially get two birds with one line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the root of your server really the DocumentRoot for the website?

i.e. is /development/flanvas/flanvas.js the absolute path to the JS file on your machine?

I would try

```
<FilesMatch ^(.*)flanvas\.js$>
   ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

or

```
<FilesMatch /path/to/documentroot/development/flanvas/flanvas.js>
   ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this is ace, but how could i do this for multiple filetypes?

Comment: Something like `<FilesMatch ^(.*)\.(js|foo|bar|baz)$>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the person that asked the question. Apparently I have no idea what account I posted this question under, but once I figure it out I'll come back and checkmark your question is it 100% worked.

Ended up using:

```
# Force download for flanvas.js
<FilesMatch ^(.*)flanvas\.js$>
 ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```